# PHP function that checks for matching numbers

Tags: php, function, while-loop

I am currently teaching myself web development/ programming and to learn php i have built a simple program. The program takes user input and based on a series of math algorithms and calculates 7 random lottery numbers. The code is working fine but i want to improve it. The code is very repetitive and i want to simplify it by creating my own functions. I have created the first function that takes the users input, simply does some maths and then returns some values.

For Example...

```
<?php 

     function some_maths($int1 $int2 $int3){

         $x = $int1 + $int2; 
         $y = $int2 * $int3; 
         $z = $y * $x; 
         return $x
         ....}
```

So this is pretty straight forward, but what i want to do now is take the values of X, Y, Z and create a function that checks to make sure they're not matching, or that they're not less than 1 or greater than 59. I used a while loop in my original code that goes like this:

```
while($x == $y || $x == $z || $x <1 || $x >59){

     if( x> 59 || x < 1){ 
       if (x<1){
           do{ $x+=$int}while($x <1);
       }elseif ($x > 59){
           do{ $x-=$int}while($x >59); 
     }else $x++; 
}
```

This seems to work fine but i don't want to have to repeat the same code over and over. I am sure there has to be a better way? Could i put the values into an array and maybe do it that way? What would be the best solution for this?

Comment: From the comments you made to the two answers so far I am tempted to downvote your question since it is unclear to me what you actually expect from us. So please clarify and/or make more constructive comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of vague but if I had to write a function to check if three numbers weren't equal and were < 59 and >1 this is how I would do it

```
function validateNumbers($x , $y , $z)
{
    if(equal($x,$y)) return false;
    if(equal($x,$z)) return false;
    if(equal($y,$z)) return false;
    if($x>59||$x<1) return false;
    if($y>59||$y<1) return false;
    if($z>59||$z<1) return false;
    return true;
}

function equal($x , $y)
{
    if($x == $y)return true;
    else return fasle;
}
```

Comment: Cool, but i am checking more than three numbers! In total i have 8 variables each variable is basically a lotto ball so they can not be equal or > 59 or < 1.

Answer (score 0):

So far I only see two (pretty straightforward) things:

1. Your function prototype in the first example is missing commas between the parameters. Instead of `function some_maths($int1 $int2 $int3)` it should read `function some_maths($int1, $int2, $int3)`.
2. In your second example a closing `}` is missing. But if I am interpreting your stuff correctly, the outer `if`-clause is redundant. Thus, the snippet can be simplified to:

Second example:

```
while($x == $y || $x == $z || $x <1 || $x >59){
    if (x<1){
        do{ $x+=$int}while($x <1);
    }
    elseif ($x > 59){
        do{ $x-=$int}while($x >59); 
    }
    else $x++;     
}
```

There may be more room for improvement (e.g. slim down the condition of the outer while loop) - but for that we would need more context (what happens before your loop, what is `$int`, ...).

Comment: its not my actual code its just an example. I have a lot more variables going into the prototype function